# Azure Synapse Analytics | Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure, azure-synapse

I have created a dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics. When I am trying to create a table in my dedicated SQL pool then it is showing below error.

> Login failed for user < token-identified principal>

Things I tried-

- Reset user credentials
- Login from multiple machines.
- Pause and resume dedicated SQL pool

User I am using has workspace admin role. Attaching screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to give SQL Active directory admin permission to access from your email-id

```
yourworkspace-->settings-->SQL Active Directory admin(left side list menu)-->setadmin  then ***save***
```

[image: Screen shot]

If you want to give access to many users you have to create security group and add user in it and assign to this SQL Active Directory admin

Comment: I am getting the same error while selecting the data from Built-in serverless SQL Pool, I don't see the SQL Active Directory for me, I see Azure Active directory where I am the admin, Still same error.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, the Access control within Synapse Studio does not apply to dedicated SQL pools. Workspace admin can create a user manually through T-SQL or they can add you through SQL Active Directory Admin option when they navigate to workspace resource in Azure Portal.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.